# How to derive Maclaurin series for ln(1+x) without calculus?

Tags: taylor-expansion

How can we show $\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots$ for $-1 < x \leq 1$ without using calculus?

Comment: Please clarify - it is not really possible even to say what $\ln(1+x)$ means without calculus.  And what does a Maclaurin series mean if you are not allowed to explain using calculus?

Comment: Clarification: can we show ln(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4 + ... for -1 < x <= 1 without differentiation or integration.  Define the natural log function as the inverse of e^x, where e is defined with the usual limit definition.

Comment: Looks difficult, as you need a definition which normally is given by calculus or a power series - both we cannot use here.  The only alternative is to use some property. e.g. from $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2 \implies \log(1+x)+\log(1-x) = \log(1-x^2)$, we get
$$\sum_0^\infty a_n(1+(-1)^n)x^n =\sum_0^\infty (-1)^na_nx^{2n} \implies 2a_{2n}=(-1)^na_n$$
Perhaps a similar approach using other suitable functions / properties could yield enough to characterise the series completely.

Answer (score 2):

Without *almost* no calculus, perform the long division $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4+\cdots$$ and integrate both sides.

Comment: (+1) On the other side, with an almost excessive amount of calculus the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ can be computed by applying the Lagrange inversion formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to the function $e^y-1$. :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. This is a very good point ! I took this question as a challenge (what does mean without calculus ?). Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The power series for binomials $\displaystyle{(1+b)^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-n+1)}{n!}b^n}$ and for exponent $\displaystyle{e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}}$ can be derived without Calculus.

Now, for a general $a=1+b$, you have $a^x=e^{(\ln a)x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln a )^n (x)^n}{n!}$.

So $\ln a=\ln (1+b)$ is the coefficient of $x$ in the expantion of $a^x=(1+b)^x$, i.e. $$\displaystyle{\ln (1+b)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{b^n}{n}}.$$